401 when authenticating swift client with rails API (using Devise)
I have a Rails API using Devise JWT for authentication.
When trying to login using Postman it works like a charm:

But when I call from my Swift app, I have a 401 Unauthorized with invalid credentials.
Here is the data I get from printing in my Swift console :
data: {"status":{"code":200,"message":"Logged in successfully.","data":{"user":{"id":null,"email":"","firstname":null,"lastname":null}}}}
It seems like the login works but I have no data associated.
I have an AuthService and a LoginViewModel as follow :
// AuthService

import Foundation

enum AuthenticationError: Error {
    case invalidCredentials
    case custom(errorMessage: String)
}

enum NetworkError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case noData
    case decodingError
}

struct LoginRequestBody: Codable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let message: String?
    let success: Bool?
}

class AuthService {
        
    func getAllUsers(token: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[UserV2], NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3001/api/users/index") else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
            
            guard let accounts = try? JSONDecoder().decode([UserV2].self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(accounts))
            
            
            
        }.resume()
        
        
    }
    
    
    func login(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3001/login") else {
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "URL is not correct")))
            return
        }
        
        let body = LoginRequestBody(email: email, password: password)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
                return
            }
            
            try! JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
            
            print("data: \(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))")
            
            guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }
            
            guard let token = loginResponse.token else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(token))
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}

// LoginViewModel

import Foundation

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    @Published var isAuthenticated: Bool = false
    
    protocol AuthenticationFormProtocol {
        var formIsValid: Bool { get }
    }
    
    func login() {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        AuthService().login(email: email, password: password) { result in
            print("result: \(result)")
            switch result {
                case .success(let token):
                    defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "jsonwebtoken")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isAuthenticated = true
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signout() {
           
           let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           defaults.removeObject(forKey: "jsonwebtoken")
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.isAuthenticated = false
           }
           
       }
    
}

I am new to Swift so maybe I'm missing something?

Your body doesn't match the one in Postman.. You're missing a hierarchy step ("user"). Add print(Sending in body: \(String(data: request.httpBody!), encoding: .utf8)") you'll see

@Larme added a struct to conform to the data. Now i have this: data: {"user":{"email":"henry.doe@test.com","password":"test1234"}} but still get a 401 with invalid credentials

Print the request header fields, and check if it's the same as the one in Postman.

Yes they are the same. I don't know why but now I don't have any 401 in my rails server, only 200 OK. But in my swift console I still have The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyAppName.AuthenticationError error 1.)

Note Apple requires https connection. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the (local) server. Have you done that?

@workingdogsupportUkraine yes i know and i have setup everything for that :)

Postman can generate Swift code for you. Try that, see if there is something amiss.

@workingdogsupportUkraine yes it's basically the same

And if you test the generated Swift code from Postman, does it work?

@Larme it's not working either, i still get invalid credentials

                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }``` this part always fails

Note, in guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().... you have completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials)) where it would clearly be a
JSONDecoding error. Replace all your try!, try? with try, and put them all inside a  do{...}catch{print(error)}
instead. Then show us exactly what error you get. I suspect you'll get a JSON decoding error.

@workingdogsupportUkraine i made your suggested changes and here we are (I print LoginResponse) : {"status":{"code":200,"message":"Logged in successfully.","data":{"user":{"id":5,"email":"henry.doe@test.com","firstname":"Henry","lastname":"Doe"}}}} LoginResponse(token: nil, message: nil, success: nil) invalidCredentials

great, so you're all good now?

(to clarify), you never saw a 401 error in swift, you just meant that  operation couldn’t be completed. (MyAppName.AuthenticationError error 1.) make you assume that Ruby had sent you a 401 HTTP status?
